# Unity 2D Performance Optimization

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm having a 2D performance issue.

I wan't to make a background like a disco floor which each hexagon part will connect to 6 hexagons it is touching and transmit a signal if something happens on them.
Hexagon part:
[image: Hexagon part]

But before that I had to spawn them in place correctly. After spawning them I realised I will have to spawn thousands of these parts in order to have a big background. And my fps started dropping drastically:

[image: Overall fps]

Each hexagon part uses triggers to connect to the other parts around. And I suppose this connection method is causing most of the issue. When I checked the profiler Physics impact was the biggest.

Here are the code for hexagon part:
`
public class HexagonPart : MonoBehaviour
{
FloorManager manager;

```
public GameObject spawnedFrom;

public HexagonPart up;
public HexagonPart down;
public HexagonPart leftUp;
public HexagonPart leftDown;
public HexagonPart rightUp;
public HexagonPart rightDown;

[SerializeField] PolygonCollider2D mainCollider;

public CircleCollider2D colliderUp;
public CircleCollider2D colliderDown;
public CircleCollider2D colliderLeftUp;
public CircleCollider2D colliderLeftDown;
public CircleCollider2D colliderRightUp;
public CircleCollider2D colliderRightDown;

SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;

private void Awake()
{
    spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

    up = null;
    leftUp = null;
    leftDown = null;
    down = null;
    rightDown = null;
    rightUp = null;

    colliderUp.enabled = true;
    colliderLeftUp.enabled = true;
    colliderLeftDown.enabled = true;
    colliderDown.enabled = true;
    colliderRightDown.enabled = true;
    colliderRightUp.enabled = true;

    manager = FindObjectOfType<FloorManager>();
    
}

private void Start()
{
    manager.parts.Enqueue(this);
}
```

}
`

The code for connection colliders (the little circle colliders around the hexagon):
`
public class HexagonCollider : MonoBehaviour
{
enum Direction
{
Up,
LeftUp,
LeftDown,
Down,
RightDown,
RightUp
}

```
[SerializeField] Direction direction;

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    
    if (collision is PolygonCollider2D)
    {
       
        if (direction == Direction.Up)
            transform.parent.GetComponent<HexagonPart>().up = collision.GetComponent<HexagonPart>();

        if (direction == Direction.LeftUp)
            transform.parent.GetComponent<HexagonPart>().leftUp = collision.GetComponent<HexagonPart>();

        if (direction == Direction.LeftDown)
            transform.parent.GetComponent<HexagonPart>().leftDown = collision.GetComponent<HexagonPart>();

        if (direction == Direction.Down)
            transform.parent.GetComponent<HexagonPart>().down = collision.GetComponent<HexagonPart>();

        if (direction == Direction.RightDown)
            transform.parent.GetComponent<HexagonPart>().rightDown = collision.GetComponent<HexagonPart>();

        if (direction == Direction.RightUp)
            transform.parent.GetComponent<HexagonPart>().rightUp = collision.GetComponent<HexagonPart>();

        GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>().enabled = false;
    }
}
```

}

`

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Hard to say without knowing what exactly you intend to do with these hexagons. However, a tried and true optimization technique is batching. Consider instead of spawning individual hexagons, spawn *groups* of hexagons, and the groups disable themselves if the player character isn't near (assuming distant hexagons have no reason to be active). Disabled groups could even be replaced with a tiled texture, which will massively reduce your object count.

Answer (score 0):

> Each hexagon part uses triggers to connect to the other parts around.

Why? When you spawn them, you already know (can calculate) the neighbors of the hexagon.

It looks like you've hung six colliders on each hexagon to determine where they touch.  But you only need one collider, and knowing the position of each, you can calculate which side they are on

```
if(pos1.x == pos2.x && pos1.y > pos2.y){
   //pos1 is on top
}
else if(pos1.x == pos2.x && pos1.y < pos2.y){
   //pos1 is down
}
else if ...
```

Also try moving the hexagons to a separate layer. And disable collisions with other layers
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am already using layers. And the circle colliders gets them dissabled after connecting.